# C++ console output not switching to a new line when the program ends

Tags: c++, bash, io, iostream, ostream

So I'm just starting to learn C++, and I'm just trying to get everything set up. When I run the compiled binary for my hello world code, it display's the console output, but doesn't switch to a new line afterwards. Here's an example:

`Hello, World!michaela@michaela-HP-Laptop-17-by4xxx: $`

I tried researching, but I can't find a good solution. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and using the BASH shell. I will provide the code if it's any help, though I doubt it as it literally just outputs "Hello, World!".

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't do anything you don't ask for. You didn't ask for a newline at the end of the output, you don't get one.

Comment: Mind you, "doesn't do" is a bit strong. It's more like "Almost never does" with a much stronger emphasis on "never" than "almost".

Comment: `std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";`

Answer (score 5):

This is completely normal for the majority of programming languages, especially in a Unix environment.  Even shell scripting will print without a newline if you use `printf` or `echo -n`.  And thanks to the terminal emulating an old teletype-like printer-based system the cursor won't reset just because a program exitted.

If you want a newline add a `'\n'` to your string or output a `std::endl` after your text.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!"<<std::endl;
```

or you can use this one :

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
```

The only difference between `std::endl` and `\n` is that `std::endl` adds `std::flush` (to flush the output stream), which is usually totally unnecessary and makes the program slower.

Comment: In this case, the flush would also be redundant. Normal termination (e.g returning from `main` flushes all the output streams. +1.

Comment: I thought `std::endl` also added a carriage return on systems where that's normal for newlines.